# C : Character swapping

Tags: c, pointers, char

I need to swap two characters by pointers but when I run this code,the program crashes.

```
int main(){
    char *s1 = "string1";
    swap(st,(st+1));

    /* BUT THIS CODE WORKS - Whats the problem?
     * char s1[] = "string1";
     * swap(s1,&s1[1]);
     */

    return 0;
}

void swap(char * const ptr1, char * const ptr2){

    char temp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;

}
```

Comment: Because, when you allocate memory for amount of characters, it's only readable, not executable or writable. When you try to write there, it gives you exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *s1 = "string1";
```

Because `s1` points to a string literal and modifying invokes [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C. That's why this doesn't work.

Whereas in this     `char s1[] = "string1";`

`s1` is an array and hence it can be modified.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal may not be modified. You try to modify `"string1"` in your code which is not allowed. Indeed, many compilers place string literals in a special section that may not be written into.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code creates a string literal which cannot be changed. It is only readable.

```
char *s1 = "string1";
```

Any attempt to change it will give you an error.

While your commented example :

```
 char s1[] = "string1";
```

creates an actual array. This can be edited and used normally.